# difference between 2 datasets with map2_df not giving the desired result within a function, but works properly when run alone

Tags: r, purrr, difference

I have this function that calculate the difference between 2 datasets, this function works perfectly on a small dataset, but when i tried it on a large data set  it is giving me an error, what i can not understand is that when i run every step alone it is working but once i run the whole function it is giving me an error.

```
# function 
soustraction.j=function(D,R,i,threshold){
  D=as.data.frame(D)
  R=as.data.frame(R)
  dif=purrr::map2_df(D[-1], R[i,-1], `-`)
  dif[dif<0] = 0
  dif$mismatch=rowSums(dif)
  dif= cbind(ID = D[1],R[1], dif)
  dif=dif[which(dif$mismatch <= threshold),]
  return(dif)
}

# trying it on a small dataset 
# small data sets
#####################################
# data frame for recipients
IDr= c(seq(1,4))
BTR=c("A","B","AB","O")
data_R=data.frame(IDr,BTR,A=rep(0,4),B=c(rep(0,3),1),C=c(rep(1,3),0),D=rep(1,4),E=c(rep(0,2),rep(1,1),0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  data_R
  IDr BTR A B C D E
1   1   A 0 0 1 1 0
2   2   B 0 0 1 1 0
3   3  AB 0 0 1 1 1
4   4   O 0 1 0 1 0

# data frame for donors 
IDd= c(seq(1,8))
BTD= c(rep("A", each=2),rep("B", each=2),rep("AB", each=2),rep("O", each=2))
WD= c(rep(0.25, each=2),rep(0.125, each=2),rep(0.125, each=2),rep(0.5, each=2))
data_D=data.frame(IDd,BTD,A=c(rep(0,6),1,1),B=c(rep(0,6),1,1),C=c(rep(1,7),0),D=rep(1,8),E=c(rep(0,6),rep(1,1),0),WD,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  data_D
  IDd BTD A B C D E    WD
1   1   A 0 0 1 1 0 0.250
2   2   A 0 0 1 1 0 0.250
3   3   B 0 0 1 1 0 0.125
4   4   B 0 0 1 1 0 0.125
5   5  AB 0 0 1 1 0 0.125
6   6  AB 0 0 1 1 0 0.125
7   7   O 1 1 1 1 1 0.500
8   8   O 1 1 0 1 0 0.500

# Applying function
 soustraction.j(data_D[,c(1, 3:7)],data_R[,c(1, 3:7)],1,3)
  IDd IDr A B C D E mismatch
1   1   1 0 0 0 0 0        0
2   2   2 0 0 0 0 0        0
3   3   3 0 0 0 0 0        0
4   4   4 0 0 0 0 0        0
5   5   1 0 0 0 0 0        0
6   6   2 0 0 0 0 0        0
7   7   3 1 1 0 0 1        3
8   8   4 1 1 0 0 0        2

###############################################
######  different datasets   #################

######### generating a pool of donor#########
set.seed(1023)
x=t(replicate(1000,rbinom(400, 1, 0.5)))
colnames(x)=paste0("epi", sprintf("%02d", 1:400))
pool1=as.data.frame(x)
duptimes <- c(5,rep(1,10),rep(0,298),rep(2,200),rep(3,100),rep(0,200),rep(1,100),rep(4,50),rep(0,40),10)
# Create an index of the rows you want with duplication
idx <- rep(1:nrow(pool1), duptimes)
# Use that index to generate the new data frame
dupdf <- pool1[idx,]
pool=rbind(pool1,dupdf)
y=runif(2025)
freq.g=y/sum(y)
BTD=replicate(2025,sample(c("A","B","AB","O"), 1, prob = c(0.42, 0.09, 0.03, 0.46)))
pooldup=as.data.frame(cbind(IDd=seq(1:2025),BTD,pool,freq.g))

pooldup[1:5,1:6]
  IDd BTD epi01 epi02 epi03 epi04
1   1   A     0     0     1     0
2   2   O     0     1     1     1
3   3   O     1     1     1     1
4   4  AB     1     0     0     0
5   5   A     1     1     1     0

######### generating recipient data#########
set.seed(1024)
x1=t(replicate(20,rbinom(400, 1, 0.5)))
colnames(x1)=paste0("epi", sprintf("%02d", 1:400))
x1r=as.data.frame(x1)
BTR=replicate(20,sample(c("A","B","AB","O"), 1, prob = c(0.42, 0.09, 0.03, 0.46)))
rdata=as.data.frame(cbind(IDr=seq(1:20),BTR,x1r))

 rdata[1:5,1:6]
  IDr BTR epi01 epi02 epi03 epi04
1   1   B     0     1     0     0
2   2   B     1     1     0     0
3   3   O     1     1     1     1
4   4   A     0     0     0     0
5   5   O     1     1     0     0

# Applying the function 
soustraction.j(pooldup[,c(1,3:402)],rdata[,c(1,3:402)],1,75)
#  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
# arguments imply differing number of rows: 2025, 20
```

When i run separately the step `purrr::map2_df(D[-1], R[i,-1],`-`)`  its working but not within the function. I apologize if my code is long i just do not understand where this error is coming from. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think i got it, i have an error in `cbind` i changed the line `dif= cbind(ID = D[1],R[1], dif)`  to `dif= cbind(ID = D[1],R[i,1], dif)` and it is working

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `cbind`. `dif` is a data frame with `2025` rows and `R` has `20` rows.

`cbind` will normally recycle values

```
cbind(1:2, 1:3)
#> [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    1
#> [2,]    2    2
#> [3,]    1    3
#> Warning message:
#>   In cbind(1:2, 1:3) :
#>   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

However, for data frames, it will error on fractional recycling

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
y <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
cbind(x, y)
#> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
#>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
```

If you want fractional recyling to work with `cbind`, convert to a `matrix` and set the number of rows

```
cbind(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 1, nrow = 3), matrix(unlist(y), ncol = 1, nrow = 3))
#>        x
#> [1,] 1 1
#> [2,] 2 2
#> [3,] 1 3
#> Warning message:
#>   In matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 1, nrow = 3) :
#>   data length [2] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [3]
```

Comment: You are right @Paul i just realized it ! i corrected the line in the `cbind` and it is working. Thank you for your response.

Comment: But Still i can not understand why it it working on my first example (the small dataset) without any modification. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your data frame rows divided nicely into each other (e.g. 2 and 4). This resulted in successful recycling. However, if they do not divide nicely, (e.g. 2 and 5) that results in fractional recycling which is an error for data frames.